# Change scrollspy link color when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

In the following example http://jsbin.com/huhavejipepi/2/edit?html,js I would change the color of the links in the navbar fixed at the top. ie. when the user is at the top of the page all the links should be black. when the user scroll down only the active scrollspy element should be black instead the others one should be light gray and change theirs color when they become active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider this:

**activate.bs.scrollspy**
This event fires whenever a new item becomes activated by the scrollspy.

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  console.log(this)
})
```

You should addClass() to the active element, and removeClass() from the other ones. Just use console.log(this) inside the event and it will be very clear what you have to do.